# Read external property files from JBoss server using Spring framework

Tags: java, spring, jboss

I'm currently working on a Spring project where in I need to read some external property files from JBoss server. I'm able to read the external property files from JBoss server with the help of [this](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HowToPutAnExternalFileInTheClasspath) article. I'm keen to know whether we can achieve this using the spring `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` or `Environment` classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is pretty straight forward. When ever we add the property files to the JBoss Server module folder($JBOSS_HOME\modules) and add the dependency in the jboss-deployment-structure.xml. All the added external property files will exist in the classpath.

We can simply use the @PropertySource and Environment class provided by the spring framework to read the property values.